# Kerberos - krendentials

Tags: kerberos

I have a different login name in the server than the local machine login name. But correct login name shows in krendentials.

When I click on get new credential action, I am getting "Unable to run aklog". What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AFS, then you can disable running aklog in kredentials' popup menu (available in kredentials 2.0-pre3 or later, released in January 2012).